# Bootstrap 3 tabs and lists

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, web-parts

I am very new with using Bootstrap 3. I am testing it on our SharePoint 2013 Intranet. I added a content editor web part and I created three tabs. Each tabs shows its own text when clicked. Is it possible to pull an existing document library or list into one of the tabs. I just can't figure that out. Also, I would like to pull blog posts into one of the tabs, is that possible.

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a community of mind readers. Please provide some code that demonstrates what you've done so far and what you've tried.

Comment: This was my first post on this forum. Your answer was not called for. I never thought SO was a community of mind readers. I thought it was one full of helpful people who were kind enough to try and help others. I did not add any code as there was none to add. I explained my issue the best  could. I was trying to add a web part to the tabs but Aaron kindly explained that was not possible. I am very new to Bootstrap. Sorry if I annoyed you with my not so perfect explanation.

Comment: My comment was called for so that you understand how SO works. People can't help you if they don't understand the question, and what you've tried. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, I guess if your way of trying to help is by being sarcastic then great. I would have said something like "I don't understand your question, please try and explain better if you can" If I had had more information to add I would have but I had nothing else. I am completely new to bootstrap. Aaron was able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Then you should accept Aaron's answer. The idea of SO is not only to help yourself, but to help everyone who might encounter a similiar problem/question. Keep that in mind when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put a separate web part zone into each tab - that way you can add whatever you want into the individual tabs.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for taking the time to reply. I am not able to do that. Here is some more info just in case I am not explaining myself. I have a content editor web part (would you suggest that?) I have three tabs created with bootstrap 3 tabs. I can add plain text to each tab but it won't allow me to add other web parts. I wonder if there is something special I need to do?

Comment: You can't add a web part to a web part. I'd suggest using a custom page layout and putting your tab markup in there. You can then add a web part zone to each tab.

Answer (score 1):

Mr Aaron´s suggestion is correct. Already tried an it worked. Create a custom page layout with the tabs you may need. Add webpart zones as needed on each DIV´s content for each tab.

```html
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="whatever-title" ID="whatever-ID"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```